# Problem with PHP PDO fetchOject

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, fetch

It seems to be a bug or problem when I use PHP `PDO fetchOject` with the query below,

Query:

```
SELECT 
    p.*,
    t.*

FROM root_pages AS p

LEFT JOIN root_templates AS t
ON p.tmp_id = t.tmp_id

WHERE p.pg_url = ?
AND ? IS NOT NULL

OR p.pg_url = ? 
AND p.pg_hide != ?
```

called from a PHP PDO db class,

```
$page = $this->database->fetch_object($sql,array(
            $pg_url,
            NULL,
            $pg_url,
            1
        ));
```

result:

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables
>   does not match number of tokens

PHP [`PDO FetchOject`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchobject.php) method from the PDO db class,

```
# return the current row of a result set as an object
    public function fetch_object($query, $params = array())
    {
        try
        {
            # prepare the query
            $stmt = $this->connection->prepare($query);

            # if $params is not an array, let's make it array with one value of former $params
            if (!is_array($params)) $params = array($params);

            # execute the query
            $stmt->execute($params);

            # return the result
            return $stmt->fetchObject();
            //return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) 
        {
            # call the get_error function
            $this->get_error($e);
        }
    }
```

It only will be fine if I call the method like this,

```
$page = $this->database->fetch_object($sql,array(
            $pg_url,
            1,
            $pg_url,
            1
        ));
```

But I can get the result without any error when I test one of the query below with `phpMyAdmin`,

```
SELECT 
    p.*,
    t.*

FROM root_pages AS p

LEFT JOIN root_templates AS t
ON p.tmp_id = t.tmp_id

WHERE p.pg_url = 'exhibition sample 6' 
AND '1' IS NOT NULL

OR p.pg_url = 'exhibition sample 6' 
AND p.pg_hide != '1'
```

or

```
SELECT 
    p.*,
    t.*

FROM root_pages AS p

LEFT JOIN root_templates AS t
ON p.tmp_id = t.tmp_id

WHERE p.pg_url = 'exhibition sample 6' 
AND NULL IS NOT NULL

OR p.pg_url = 'exhibition sample 6' 
AND p.pg_hide != '1'
```

Any ideas what I have missed when using `fetchOject`?

**EDIT:**

```
$sql ="
SELECT 
    p.*,
    t.*

FROM root_pages AS p

LEFT JOIN root_templates AS t
ON p.tmp_id = t.tmp_id


WHERE p.pg_url = 'exhibition sample 6' 
AND ? IS NOT NULL

OR p.pg_url = 'exhibition sample 6' 
AND p.pg_hide != '1'
";
```

No error with

```
$item = $connection->fetch_assoc($sql,1);
```

or

```
$item = $connection->fetch_assoc($sql,NULL);
```

the `fetch_assoc` method,

```
    # fetch a single row of result as an array ( =  one dimensional array)
public function fetch_assoc($query, $params = array())
{
    try
    {
        # prepare the query
        $stmt = $this->connection->prepare($query);

        # if $params is not an array, let's make it array with one value of former $params
        if (!is_array($params)) $params = array($params);

        # execute the query
        $stmt->execute($params);

        # return the result
        return $stmt->fetch();
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) 
    {
        # call the get_error function
        $this->get_error($e);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do (pass in `null` as a parameter to `execute`) is not possible. As the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) states:

> input_parameters
>
> An array of values with as many elements as there are bound parameters
>   in the SQL statement being executed. **All values are treated as
>   PDO::PARAM_STR**.

If you want to pass in a `null`, you have to bind the parameters with

```
$stmt->bindValue(1, null, PDO::PARAM_NULL);
```

or use the equivalent syntax for named parameters.

Comment: thanks Jon, please check my edit above. I can pass `null` with `fetch` without binding the data. how come?

Comment: I have found the mistake in my class. nothing wrong with passing null into fetchObject. thanks for the help.